# How do I convert a RAID 4 array to RAID 0?

Tags: raid, disk, mdadm, disk-management

I had a three-disk RAID 0 array and ran the following to add a fourth disk:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md127 --add /dev/xvdi
```

Each disk is a 1TB EC2 volume. The array took about 40 hours to reshape. About 1 hour through, reshaping stopped and the volume became inaccessible. I restarted the machine and reshaping continued then finished seemingly successfully, but the array level is now reported as RAID 4 and the useable capacity hasn't changed.

`mdadm --detail /dev/md127` now reports the following:

```
/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed Jul  1 22:26:36 2015
     Raid Level : raid4
     Array Size : 4294965248 (4096.00 GiB 4398.04 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1073741312 (1024.00 GiB 1099.51 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sun Oct 11 07:40:48 2015
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : [removed]
           UUID : [removed]
         Events : 63530

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     202      160        0      active sync   /dev/xvdk
       1     202      144        1      active sync   /dev/xvdj
       2     202       80        2      active sync   /dev/xvdf
       4     202      128        3      active sync   /dev/xvdi
       4       0        0        4      removed
```

My aim here is to have a 4TB RAID 0 array. I don't need redundancy since I backup by taking volume snapshots in AWS. I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04.3.

How do I switch to RAID 0, without losing any data, taking into account the fact that the state is `clean, degraded`?

Comment: I happen to have a test box here, and am trying to replicate.  Unfortunately, I can't add a disk to the array in the same way you did: "mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/sdf as 3: Invalid argument" - so I think there's something to how you originally created the array that led to it adding the disk as a parity disk.

Comment: Not sure about that Paul, a 4 disk stripe, is basically a 5 disk raid 4, with the parity disk missing.  It looks like it created the stripe set, but for some reason thinks it's raid 4 with the parity disk missing.  I don't know enough about software raid to know why it thinks it's raid4, but my experience of software raid, is that when it breaks, you lose data.  My advice (not what you want to hear) is do a full backup/restore, to a blanked disk, and this time use LVM to increase your logical partition size, rather than raid (if you don't need redundancy)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the current configuration directly to a RAID with `mdadm -G -l 0 /dev/md127`.  Since a RAID 4 with only 4 of 5 members is essentially a RAID 0 without a parity stripe, the conversion will occur instantly.  If there was a parity member, it would be dropped, but since it's already listed as "Removed", it will simply be dropped, Raid Devices decremented to 4, and state should be "clean".

From the mdadm query printed above, you can see that the member size is 1TB and the volume size is 4TB, so the volume should be usable as is, even without the parity member.  You will then need to [grow the partition with parted](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/parted_31.html) and perform filesystem resize operations per usual.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old, but these steps could be helpful to folks.

**How to add disks to RAID-0?**

Env:

1. centos 7  (kernel: 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64)
2. mdadm version v3.4 - 28th January 2016
3. First 3 disks of 10GB each
4. Fourth disk also 10GB

**Initial setup:**

```
$ sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --name=DB_RAID2 --raid-devices=3 /dev/xvdh /dev/xvdi /dev/xvdj
$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  5 14:25:10 2017
     Raid Level : raid0
     Array Size : 31432704 (29.98 GiB 32.19 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Sep  5 14:25:10 2017
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : temp:DB_RAID2  (local to host temp)
           UUID : e8780813:5adbe875:ffb0ab8a:05f1352d
         Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     202      112        0      active sync   /dev/xvdh
       1     202      128        1      active sync   /dev/xvdi
       2     202      144        2      active sync   /dev/xvdj

$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/md0
$ sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/test
```

**Add a disk to RAID-0 in one-step (doesn't work):**

```
$ sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=4 --add /dev/xvdk
mdadm: level of /dev/md0 changed to raid4
mdadm: added /dev/xvdk
mdadm: Failed to initiate reshape!
```

Probably, this fails due to this [bug](https://www.spinics.net/lists/raid/msg51022.html).

**Step-1: Convert to RAID-4:**

```
$ sudo mdadm --grow --level 4 /dev/md0
mdadm: level of /dev/md0 changed to raid4
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid4 xvdj[2] xvdi[1] xvdh[0]
      31432704 blocks super 1.2 level 4, 512k chunk, algorithm 5 [4/3] [UUU_]

unused devices: <none>
```

**Step-2: Add a disk:**

```
$ sudo mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/xvdk
mdadm: added /dev/xvdk
```

Wait till recovers:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid4 xvdk[4] xvdj[2] xvdi[1] xvdh[0]
      31432704 blocks super 1.2 level 4, 512k chunk, algorithm 5 [4/3] [UUU_]
      [=>...................]  recovery =  8.5% (893572/10477568) finish=3.5min speed=44678K/sec

$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid4 xvdk[4] xvdj[2] xvdi[1] xvdh[0]
      31432704 blocks super 1.2 level 4, 512k chunk, algorithm 5 [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

**Step-3: Convert to RAID-0 back:**

```
$ sudo mdadm --grow --level 0 --raid-devices=4 /dev/md0
$
```

Wait till it reshapes:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid4 xvdk[4] xvdj[2] xvdi[1] xvdh[0]
      31432704 blocks super 1.2 level 4, 512k chunk, algorithm 5 [5/4] [UUUU_]
      [===>.................]  reshape = 16.2% (1702156/10477568) finish=6.1min speed=23912K/sec

$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid0 xvdk[4] xvdj[2] xvdi[1] xvdh[0]
      41910272 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
```

**Step-4: Resize the Filesystem:**

```
$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  5 14:25:10 2017
     Raid Level : raid0
     Array Size : 41910272 (39.97 GiB 42.92 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Sep  5 14:55:46 2017
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : temp:DB_RAID2  (local to host temp)
           UUID : e8780813:5adbe875:ffb0ab8a:05f1352d
         Events : 107

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     202      112        0      active sync   /dev/xvdh
       1     202      128        1      active sync   /dev/xvdi
       2     202      144        2      active sync   /dev/xvdj
       4     202      160        3      active sync   /dev/xvdk
$ df -h
/dev/md0         30G   45M   28G   1% /mnt/test
```

Actual resize and after resize:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/md0
resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Filesystem at /dev/md0 is mounted on /mnt/test; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 4, new_desc_blocks = 5
The filesystem on /dev/md0 is now 10477568 blocks long.

$ df -h /dev/md0
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0         40G   48M   38G   1% /mnt/test
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one scenario where I end up with a degraded FAILED array. It goes like this:

- create a RAID0 striping array
- Convert it to RAID4
- Add a parity disk to the RAID4 array
- Fail one of the other disks in the array and remove it
- Convert the RAID4 array to RAID0

In the last step, the parity disk is dropped and then it finds out it cannot convert the array to RAID0. However, it could have known that before hand (apparently it requires all non-parity disks to be online). The results is an array in clean, degraded state.

## convert RAID0 striping to RAID4

mdadm --grow /dev/md/vg_docker --level=4
mdadm --detail /dev/md/vg_docker

## add a parity disk

mdadm --manage /dev/md/vg_docker --add /dev/sdm
mdadm --detail /dev/md/vg_docker

## wait until rebuild is finished

## fail one of the original disks in the RAID0 array

mdadm --manage /dev/md/vg_docker --fail /dev/sde
mdadm --detail /dev/md/vg_docker

## remove it from the array

mdadm --manage /dev/md/vg_docker --remove /dev/sde
mdadm --detail /dev/md/vg_docker

## convert it back to a RAID0 stripe

mdadm --grow /dev/md/vg_docker --level=stripe

Gives output: mdadm: /dev/md/vg_docker: could not set level to raid0

mdadm --detail /dev/md/vg_docker

State is now clean, FAILED, and all data is lost.

Would be good if mdadm could check before converting the array to a RAID0 stripe if the operation could be done.

Background: RAID0 striping is useful to get more performance in a cloud setup. The underlying storage is already high available so RAID is only needed for additional performance. The above was from some experiments trying to replace a disk in a RAID0 array with another disk by adding a new disk (parity) and then removing the disk we want to remove. Then converting back to RAID0 should give the required result where one disk is replaced.